# Proof or source for this Hurwitz Zeta function identity?

Tags: special-functions, zeta-functions

I need a proof or source for this identity:

$ \zeta '\left(z,\frac{q}{2}\right)-2^z \zeta '(z,q)+\zeta '\left(z,\frac{q+1}{2}\right)=\zeta(z,q)2^{z}\ln 2$

Here the derivative means the derivative by the first variable.

Any similar identities, particular cases and generalizations are very much appreciated.

Comment: What's the reference for this identity?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal this is exactly I am asking for.

Comment: My question is: where did you find this identity?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal I do not remember, it was long ago, so I lost the link to the source. I only can say I found it in an article published in the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This identity follows from the following distribution relation on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Relation_to_Dirichlet_L-functions):
$$\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\zeta\left(z,a+\frac{m}{n}\right)=n^z\zeta\left(z,na\right).\tag{1}$$
It suffices to set therein $a=\frac{q}{2}$, $n=2$ and differentiate once with respect to $z$.

Comment: Sorry but where do u see the relation on the wikipedia page?

Comment: @Anixx It's the last formula in the subsection "Relation to Dirichlet $L$-functions".